# qWait analogue in PySide?

Tags: pyqt, pyside, qtestlib

I've written a series of unit tests in PyQt using QTest and unittest. My code passes signals around, so to ensure that sufficient time has gone by after an operation before testing, I throw in some qWaits.

```
APP.ui.serverPortEdit.setText('1234')
QTest.mouseClick(APP.ui.userConnectButton, Qt.LeftButton)
QTest.qWait(2000) #wait for the server to connect
self.checkOnline()
```

I'd like to run the same tests in PySide, but I can find no analogue to qWait. Have I overlooked something? The PySide [qTest docs](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtTest/QTest.html) make no mention of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use python's time.sleep()?

Comment: It looks like I can in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For others that come across this (my first Google hit) `time.sleep()` does not process `QEvent`s. I came across this [PyQt4/PySide wrapper](http://sparkle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/sparkle/QtWrapper.html) that defines qWait to use with PySide:

```
from datetime import datetime as datetime_, timedelta

@staticmethod
def qWait(t):
    end = datetime_.now() + timedelta(milliseconds=t)
    while datetime_.now() < end:
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
QtTest.QTest.qWait = qWait
```